# hex char to decimal and store output as char

Tags: c++, hex, decimal

I am writing a hex to dec conversion function. The input is a single character which is converted to hex and returned back as a char.
Here is the function

```
char hex2dec(char inp)
{
    char out;
    cout << "inp:" << inp;

    if(inp >= '0' && inp <='9')
    {
        out = (inp - '0');
        cout << " out " << out;
    }
    else 
    {
        out = (toupper(inp) - 'A' + 10);
        cout << " out " << out;
    }

    return out;
}
```

When i pass '0' and 'A' to the function, the print i get is
inp:0 out 
inp:A out 
i.e nothing is printed in out.

I am not able to find the issue..Can anyone help?

Comment: Your description is not making sense. If it's a hex to dec converter, then why is the input character "converted to hex"? It should already be hex. Also, it's not converting "to dec", it's converting to number.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `iostream` library? Everything you need is already there. BTW, what are you going to do with this after conversion? Print it as hex value?

Comment: `cout` doesn't exist in `C`. Also you are not converting hex to dec, you are converting hexstr/-char to binary.

Comment: @Devolus: It's tagged with C++ - I guess that's all you need to know.

Comment: this is what i am trying to do
eg: 0A

char dec1= hex2dec(0);
char dec2 = hextodec(A);
char dec3 = (dec1 << 4) + dec2;

dec3 will be in decimal

Comment: @thokra, then what's the `c` tag for? There are problems wich can be solved in C or in C++ as the languages have common features, but this is strictly related to C++ (wrong usage of cout), therfore the tag doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: i am writing in c++.. not C..

Comment: @Devolus: It's wrong to include the C++ tag in purely C related question but it usually not wrong to include the C tag in an obvious C++ question.

Comment: @thokra, it depends on the problem, but I guess the OP didn't know it, otherwise he wouldn't have to ask the question in the first place. :) Well, I guess there are more important things to do, then nitpicking about wrong tags.

Comment: @Anthea: If you are asking for help - please appreciate other people efforts by choosing your answer. Otherwise you discourage people and next time they will not answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually trying to print is ascii characters with codes [0-15] which are not printable characters ie you want to print 15 but you print "\x0f" etc

use:

> cout << (int)out;

and you'll force cout to invoke method printing ints not chars - this will solve your issue.

..or more 'c++++ ish' ;-)

> cout << static_cast(out);

..or this which for most looks weird:

> cout << int(out);

Comment: I realize it's a preference thing, but I think `cout << int(out)` (or just making `out` an `int` to begin with, is somewhat cleaner. Use C casts in C, but use C++ facilities when writing C++...

Answer (score 0):

Use `int out` instead of `char out`.  `cout` prints `char` as a character not an integer. The ASCII values 0-15 are unprintable control characters.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `std::stringstream` for this purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  // use hex formatting
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << std::hex << 'A';

  // retrieve value of the hex input character
  int value;
  stream >> value;
  std::cout << value << std::endl; // prints 10

  // reset the stream
  stream.str ();
  stream.clear();

  // also works for strings
  stream << "0xABC" << std::endl;
  stream >> value;
  std::cout << value << std::endl; // prints 2748

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The user starts with a hex character not an integer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Should be fixed now. Kind of twisted the OP's intent there.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why u got an 'A' from print is that out is char ,and after 'A' - 'A' + 10, out is a character whose ascii value is 10 instead of integer 10. So u will get a character whose ascii value is 10 instead of getting 'A'.After checking the ascii table, that character is null,which can explain why u get nothing in the output.